# Is it possible to get the call stack of Excel worksheet functions?

Tags: excel, debugging, crash, stack, call

I am trying to debug a workbook that has external add-ins and crashes unexpectedly without warning (window just disappears and process dies). Is there any way that I can log the functions calls that excels is doing on calculations so that I can see the last excel (or VBA) function that got called before the crash??

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way of accessing the dynamic calculation chain.

I would try switching to Manual Calc mode and re-calculating each worksheet in turn (Shift-F9 to recalc the active sheet) to see if you can isolate the problem to a worksheet.

The use Range.Calculate (you can download my RangeCalc addin from http://www.decisionmodels.com/downloads.htm  to try to isolate to a block of cells and then a formula.